# How to make CORS origin call request from rally sdk (custom html code)?

Tags: extjs, cors, rally, code-rally

I'm developing a custom html dashboard using the rally sdk and I want to populate one of the field data from a CORS origin request call.

Can you please provide some examples/links how to make CORS call using rally sdk custom html code?

I tried via ajax call it gives me 403 exception.

```
var usChangeSets = story.getCollection('Changesets');
            console.log('usChangeSets--',usChangeSets);         
            usChangeSets.load({
                fetch : ['Author', 'Message', 'Uri'],
                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(changeset){                                           
                       //Ajax api call to get details from external link
                        var blink ="https://[sonarqube]/job/Appdev/job/TestProject/api/json";                       
                         Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: blink, 
                                method :'GET',
                                crossDomain: true,
                                withCredentials: true,  
                                headers : { 
                                    'Authorization': 'Basic dsasfsfxfhfj',
                                     'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                                     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
                                },
                                success: function(response){
                                    var backToJs=JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                                        console.log('resp data-',backToJs);
                                        //console.log(backToJs['QueryResult'].Results);

                                },
                                failure: function(response) {
                                    console.log('ajax call failure');
                                }
                            });                                
                        }
            }
}
```

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45628458/edit to edit/update your question and paste in the exact error message you’re seeing in your browser devtools console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your external server to allow CORS requests. The browser will automatically add the `origin` header to your request and then your server should respond with the appropriate cors headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).

Here's an example of how the rally server responds to a request from a different origin:

```
% http https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcaseresult/54277371431 zsessionid:_5507Kn8 origin:localhost -v
GET /slm/webservice/v2.0/testcaseresult/54277371431 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: rally1.rallydev.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9
origin: localhost
zsessionid: _55GAn8



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
CF-RAY: 38cbe03c4dd45005-DEN
Cache-Control: private,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 623
Content-Type: application/json;  charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2017 14:27:29 GMT
ETag: "0b0e0cdae135fc6cd32fa496d7660c756"
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
P3P: CP="NON DSP COR CURa PSAa PSDa OUR NOR BUS PUR COM NAV STA"
RallyRequestID: qs-app-103xz471u80pea8opfovz9g8gv.qs-app-1014978663
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d604a6a0fa131613b997640ead95cc5171502461649; expires=Sat, 11-Aug-18 14:27:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.rallydev.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=qs-a0;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: SUBBUCKETID=209;Path=/;Domain=rally1.rallydev.com;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: SUBSCRIPTIONID=209;Path=/;Domain=rally1.rallydev.com;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=319fca23748f5704e88bd8741ae60476b188cf5e; path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload;
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```